# I have a code that sums the total of ages from a dictionary but my output prints the items before printing the sum

Tags: python

```
    def get_users():
    John = {'name':'John','phone':'234','country':'Nigeria' ,'age': 38}
    Mary = {'name':'Mary','phone':'235','country':'Nigeria', 'age': 30}
    Angel = {'name':'Angel','phone':'235','country':'Nigeria', 'age': 40}
    return [John,Mary,Angel]

def total_age():
    user_age = []
    users = get_users()

    for user in users:
        # print(user)
        x = user['age']
        user_age.append(x)
        total = sum(user_age)
        print(total)

total_age()
```

This programme prints the ages first before printing the sum. I want the programme to print only sum. The output is 38 68 108. How do I fix this please.

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating the total for every iteration of the loop. You're then printing out the running total as the loop is happening. Put the `sum` and `print` outside of the loop:

```
for user in users:
    # print(user)
    x = user['age']
    user_age.append(x)
total = sum(user_age)
print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. it worked